# How to count the times values of one df.column, are a part of another df.column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to different dataframes, with both containing a column of object types. Both column exist of combinations of values. I want to know how often the combinations in the second dataframe, occur in combinations of the first dataframe.

I tried different variations of:

```
df1.Column1.str.count(df2['Column2'])
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

df1 = 
Index                         Column1 
0                             BIER, VRUCHTENSAP, SMOOTHIE
1                                       FRISDRANK, KOFFIE
2                                           KOFFIE, WATER
3                                            KOFFIE, THEE
4                                       FRISDRANK, KOFFIE
5                                   HOT CHOCOLATE, KOFFIE
6                                            KOFFIE, THEE
7                                       FRISDRANK, KOFFIE
8                                         BIER, FRISDRANK
9                                       FRISDRANK, KOFFIE
10                                 BIER, MIX DRINKS, THEE
11                                           KOFFIE, THEE

df2 = 
Index                         Column2
1                    KOFFIE, SPECIAAL BIER
2                             KOFFIE, THEE
3                            KOFFIE, WATER
```

The expected result is a dataframe showing the count of the values in df2, and the time they occurred in df1:

```
Index                         Count
KOFFIE, SPECIAAL BIER         0
KOFFIE, THEE                  3 
KOFFIE, WATER                 1
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for exact matches you can use the following list comprehension, counting the amount of exact matches with [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
counts = [df1.Column1.eq(i).sum() for i in df2.Column2]
pd.DataFrame({'Count':counts}, df2.Column2)

                        Count
Column2                   
KOFFIE, SPECIAAL BIER      0
KOFFIE, THEE               3
KOFFIE, WATERE             1
```

Comment: What if I am not looking for exact matches in df1, but also if the value is a part of the value in df1?

Comment: For that have a look at `str.contains`. However this is a new answer, I suggest you post it as a new question and you'll most likely get it answered :)

Answer (score 0):

`.value_counts` + `.reindex` will work for exact matches.

```
df1.Column1.value_counts().reindex(df2.Column2).fillna(0).astype(int)

Column2
KOFFIE, SPECIAAL BIER    0
KOFFIE, THEE             3
KOFFIE, WATER            1
Name: Column1, dtype: int32
```